# Name of BI Publisher Reports

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I am developing reports using BI Publisher 11.1.7.
The problem is that when end user downloads the report. The name of file is like this **"report name_layout name"** and space exist in name are replaced by %20 which looks quite wired.

Is there any way to specify the names of the generated report file

Answer (score 1):

I think this replacement is done by your web server or browser. Some browsers replace the space with %20, and some with + signs.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in 'Edit layout' at 'label and formatting'